# How to make a webform block specific template?

Tags: theming, webforms

i would to make a custom tpl for a webform in a block.I get is ID but actually i can't it to works.what the way to do this ? what si the folder / files structure to do this ?
i'm on drupal 6 and webform 3.x

thanks

EDIT: this my code for node-webform.tpl

```
<!-- NODE-WEBFORM.TPL GENERIK -->
<div class="node<?php if ($sticky) { print " sticky"; } ?><?php if (!$status) { print " node-unpublished"; } ?>">

     <!--______________COLONNE GAUCHE 1________________ -->

<div id="col_G1" class="colG1_webform">
     <?php if ($title): /*insertion du titre de la page et style differencié*/?>
     <h1 class="titre_pl"><?php print $title; ?></h1>

    <?php endif; ?>
      <br clear="all"/>
       <!-- Deco page-->

    <?php  print $node->field_image_deco_lycee[0]['view'] /*Image deco page lycee*/ ?>
</div>
<!--______________COLONNE GAUCHE 2________________ -->
<div id="col_G2" class="colG2_webform">
     <?php if ($submitted) { ?>
    <span class="submitted"><?php print $submitted?></span>
  <?php }; ?>



  <div class="content">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td><?php print $node->content['body']['#value']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><?php print $node->content['webform']['#value']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

    <?php if ($links): ?>
    <div class="links"> <?php print $links; ?></div>
  <?php endif; ?>

     <?php if ($terms) { ?>
    <span class="taxonomy"><?php print $terms?></span>
  <?php }; ?>

</div>
<!--______________COLONNE GAUCHE 3________________ -->

<div id="col_G3" class="colG3_webform">
     <?php print $picture; ?>



    <div class="content">

        <br clear="all"/>
           <?php if ($node->field_vue_actus_lycee[0]['view']): ?>
        <div id="bloc-actu-lycee">
           <?php  print $node->field_vue_actus_lycee[0]['view'] /*Vue actus du lycée*/ ?>
        </div>
           <?php endif;?>
    </div>

    <?php if ($terms): ?>
      <div class="taxonomy"><?php //print $terms; ?></div>
    <?php endif;?>



</div>



  <?php if ($picture) { print $picture; }?>

  <?php if ($page == 0) { ?>
    <?php if ($title) { ?>
      <h2 class="title"><a href="<?php print $node_url?>"><?php print $title?></a></h2>
    <?php }; ?>
  <?php }; ?>

<div class="clear-block clear"></div>

</div><!-- /node -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy (not move) sites/all/modules/webform/templates/webform-form.tpl.php to sites/all/themes/yourTheme/templates/webform-form-nid.tpl.php (obviously replace yourTheme and nid) and clear caches.

Comment: is it block id the same as webform id in this case ?

Comment: Oh sorry, it should be the node id of the webform. But yes, what you said is correct. Editing my answer now.

Comment: actually i have a node-webform.tpl + webform-form.tpl files.It seem that if i wuould to make a specific webform tpl, i must add a page-webform-ID.tpl to my theme files,not ? what kind of files do you use to do this ?

Comment: As I said in my answer, you must copy the existing `sites/all/modules/webform/templates/webform-form.tpl.php` to `sites/all/themes/yourTheme/templates/webform-form-nid.tpl.php`. For instance, if your theme is called marinelli and your webform node id 100, the full path becomes `sites/all/themes/marinelli/templates/webform-form-100.tpl.php`.

Comment: yes i understand that, but i get issue because i'm using node-webform.tpl otherwise.i think about a conflict between node-webform and webform-form.Or perhaps i need to create both files for my webform block ?

Comment: No, you do not need node-webform.tpl.php at all.

Comment: ok,it's better but how can i add html + css to the webform-form.tpl  as i do with the node-webform.tpl ? because the webform-form.tpl is all php code inside..i edit the fist post to show what's in my node-webform.tpl

Comment: You can copy that (not move for testing purposes) to `sites/all/themes/yourTheme/templates/webform-form-nid.tpl.php` and clear caches. After making sure it works as expected, you can move node-webform.tpl.php elsewhere.

Comment: after testing, the form isn't display, so i go to find a code example for this kind of file.the tpl is the right one.But the others forms are not styled because node-webform is missing..

Comment: need to print the webform title into my webform-form-ID.tpl but i d'on't find how..someone knows ?

Comment: Why do you need to? You normally shouldn't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21403/discussion-between-kartagis-and-webmaster-pf).